# How do I detect when InnerHtml has a mix of text and nested child elements?

Tags: c#, dom

In c#
I have two functions that iterate over HtmlElements of an HtmlDocument
The problem that i'm having is when i hit an element
that contains a mix of text and child elements, the text portion of that element
is ignored.  For example if hit a node like:
< div > hello1 < div > hello2 < / div > hello3 < / div >.

My function will only
pick up hello2, while hello1 and hello3 are ignored.  I would really like to keep the solution without having
to convert the HtmlElement to an XElement.  Is there a way to get hello1 and hello3?

```
private static XElement FlattenChildren(this HtmlDocument htmlDoc, string rootname, string rowname)
    {
        XElement result = new XElement(rootname);
        List<XElement> resultList = new List<XElement>();
        HtmlElement htmlRoot = htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

        foreach (HtmlElement elem in htmlRoot.Children)
        {
            if (elem.Children.Count == 0)
            {
                if (elem.IgnoreTag() == false && elem.HasQualifiedValue() == true)
                {
                    string gr = elem.GetAttribute("gr");
                    string gs = elem.GetAttribute("gs");
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gr) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(gs) == false)
                    {
                        XElement newelem = new XElement(rowname);
                        newelem.SetAttributeValue("gr", gr);
                        newelem.SetAttributeValue("gs", gs);
                        newelem.Value = elem.InnerText;
                        resultList.Add(newelem);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FlattenChildrenIter(elem, rowname, ref resultList);
            }
        }
        foreach (var xelem in resultList)
        {
            result.Add(xelem);
        }
        return result;
    }

private static void FlattenChildrenIter(HtmlElement p, string rowname, ref List<XElement> resultList)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in p.Children)
        {
            if (elem.Children.Count == 0)
            {
                if (elem.IgnoreTag() == false && elem.HasQualifiedValue() == true)
                {
                    string gr = elem.GetAttribute("gr");
                    string gs = elem.GetAttribute("gs");
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gr) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(gs) == false)
                    {
                        XElement newelem = new XElement(rowname);
                        newelem.SetAttributeValue("gr", gr);
                        newelem.SetAttributeValue("gs", gs);
                        newelem.Value = elem.InnerText;
                        resultList.Add(newelem);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (elem.CountXText() > 0)
                {
                    var test = 5;
                }
                FlattenChildrenIter(elem, rowname, ref resultList);
            }
        }
    }
    private static int CountXText(this HtmlElement e)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = XElement.Parse(e.OuterHtml); //<----this Parsing does not work all the time????
            var textNodes = from c in p.Nodes()
                            where c.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                            select (XText)c;

            return textNodes.Count();
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the problematic piece of html to this question, along with the javascript that doesn't work?

Comment: Show your code / what language?

Comment: did you mean `<hello1/> hello2 <hello3/>`

Comment: This is pretty simple in CsQuery (just like pretty much everything else in scraping and such) if you're willing to consider it.